# Offline Scorm Player for Android

Tags: android, android-webview, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I need to display and track the scorm content in a android application. I have search some post related to scorm player for mobile devices and it was closed too. I have already display the content using *imsmanifest.xml*

I am stuck with the tracking of LMS in the scorm file. After a long search, I found that I need to execute a JavaScript file for interacting with the scorm file and the application as Scorm_1.2 and Scorm_1.3 for old and newer version of scorm. I have executed the JavaScript too but its not communicating with the scorm file.

It always returning null value for the API object call from the JavaScript from scorm

```
if (win.API != null) {                 
    return win.API; //It always null value
}
else {

    if (win.frames.length > 0) {        
        for (var i = 0; i < win.frames.length; i++) {
            if (win.frames[i] && win.frames[i].API != null) //Here too it comes null value
                alert(win.frames[i].API);
                return win.frames[i].API;
        }
    }
    if (typeof(win.opener) != "undefined" && win.opener != null)    {
        return findAPI(win.opener);             
    }
    if (win.parent != window && win.parent != win) {
        return findAPI(win.parent);             
    }
    return null;
}
```

Due to null value from the JavaScript its not communicating with the JavaScript in Scorm_1.2

Comment: i am implemented offline scorm player with sync to moodle server. Its really a tough job not that easy .

Comment: @AshishNautiyal can you please explain how to sync to moodle server in offline player. Its urgent to resolve this issues.

Comment: its normal database sync

Comment: Sync with the normal database is fine but my question was how to render the scorm and get the values from scorm player in android webview.

Comment: you have to impement scorm . its a big question

Answer (score 0):

SCORM is designed to be run from a web browser, not an app. The LMS must launch the course in a popup window or frameset, and the window/frameset must provide the SCORM API in the form of a JavaScript object.

Offline and mobile use cases (like yours) are one of the driving forces behind the [Experience API](http://tincanapi.com/) (aka Tin Can).

As mentioned in [other StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042479/offline-scorm-players-for-mobile-devices), there are commercial solutions that provide offline support, but technically they skirt the rules of the SCORM specification.

Comment: yes i am rendering the html in webview with the frameset only but javascript object returns always null values.